# Moving all wordpress posts from 50 websites to another website

Tags: plugins, posts, migration

I have 50 websites (wordpress) and I want to move all the posts (with images, links etc.) from those 49 websites to only one website and I know that I can do it single by plugin but - is there an easy way to automate and speed it up this process?

Comment: You can export from all 50 sites using the default WP importer/exporter, then import them all on the target site. Plugin recommendations are off topic here though, if it's a plugin you are asking for you will need to ask elsewhere

Comment: If there are lots of media items, the WP export / import scripts will struggle - how much depends on your server setup - merging databases directly will be complex, due to relational data in meta tables.. how different technically are the 50 sites?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

- 'freezing' new posts/content/changes
- copying entire file structure of the sites from one host to another
- copy all site's databases to the new host
- reset credentials on databases on new site to credentials on old site
- set your local 'hosts' file to redirect your domain.com to the IP address of the new place
- you might need to temporarily change htaccess on the new place to use IP address rather than existing domain name. Change it back when you get your nameservers pointing to the new host.

Because you copied the database and files from old to new (ensuring credentials match), the new site should work just like the old site. And media links won't have to be changed, since your domain name is not changing.

There are 'cloning' plugins available that will work. I've used one called "WP Clone" mostly successfully.